# Keep getting error on basic syntax with if statement

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I keep getting the following error when verifying the formula. This is in crystal reports on Basic syntax:

> A statement is expected here.

**Code:**

```
if {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "Prep" Then ({JobOperations.jmoProcessID} in ("BOELE","BOEHY","BOPRA","BOPRS"))
else 
if {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "Main" then ({JobOperations.jmoProcessID} not in 
("BOELE","BOEHY","BOPRA","BOPRS"))
else
if {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "All" then "All"
```

[image]

Comment: It might help if you try and explain the logic for how this formula should work.  Especially the IN and NOT IN statements that are found between your Then and Else If structures.  Normally the statements found after a Then would be something that provides output, but you have code that tests for a field's value within a list of strings.  The output of such a statement can only be True or False.  As its written, I can't determine what you want to accomplish in order to begin to evaluate syntax.

Comment: Hello, Basically i have a drop down box that when selecting a option only the certain data is displayed. for example: if Prep is selected then only the operations with a process ID of "BOELE","BOEHY","BOPRA","BOPRS" are displayed. then if main is selected everything apart from "BOELE","BOEHY","BOPRA","BOPRS" is displayed. If all is selected then everything is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong, if statement shouldn't be declared in that way.

Try this:

```
if {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "Prep" and ({JobOperations.jmoProcessID} in ("BOELE","BOEHY","BOPRA","BOPRS"))
then {JobOperations.jmoProcessID}
else 
if {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "Main" and not({JobOperations.jmoProcessID} in 
("BOELE","BOEHY","BOPRA","BOPRS"))
then {JobOperations.jmoProcessID} 
else
if {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "All" then "All"
```

edit-----------------------------------------------------------------

```
 if {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "Prep" and ({JobOperations.jmoProcessID} in ("BOELE","BOEHY","BOPRA","BOPRS"))
    then Formula = {JobOperations.jmoProcessID}
    elseif {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "Main" and not({JobOperations.jmoProcessID} in 
    ("BOELE","BOEHY","BOPRA","BOPRS"))
    then Formula ={JobOperations.jmoProcessID} 
    elseif {?Pm-?dropdown_Barcodes} = "All" 
then Formula ="All"
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. but this prompts an error saying "The ) is missing"

Comment: check now their is no space between `and` and `(`

Comment: nope still not working, the code is expecting a ) after the "BOELE" on the first line

Comment: nope i get "A number, currency amount, boolean, Date, Time etc etc is expected here"

Comment: at which line it is prompting?

Comment: first line where you changed the ( to a [. I'm starting to get the feeling i.ve not got something setup correctly.

Comment: sorry its a basic syntax, didn't notice, can you check my edit now

Comment: still getting the above error on the first line at the ["BOELE"....... Ignore this i see you changed the brackets back to ( and ) but i'm getting the first error again. "Expecting )"

Comment: yeah i noticed that. but getting the "Expecting )" message again now.

Comment: can you post the image of CR window?

Comment: image added to original post

Comment: not still getting the "Expecting ) after the "BOELE",

Comment: I have replicated same at my end and its working fine

Comment: ok their was a type instead of `in` typed `n` changed can you check now